# Cooling system blockage in block or heads?

Tags: chevrolet, cooling-system, overheating, silverado

Hot water is entering the passenger side of the radiator, but no hot water is entering the inlet side of the radiator. I've replaced the radiator, water pump, and thermostat. The truck is a 1994 Chevrolet Silverado 4WD pickup, 5.7L.  The truck overheats.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Which 1994 Chevrolet? You could be talking about the 5.7 Gen1 SBC or the Gen2 SBC, and depending on the car, could be a completely different solution to your issue. What have you done to the car?

Comment: Its a 1994 silveradoe 4WD pickup

Comment: Replaced radiator, water pump and thermostat.

Comment: What is the actual issue ... is it overheating? (I hate to assume that's the issue.) And was the issue the reason for changing all of the parts?

Comment: Yes, I get hot water to radiator return side ie water pump inlet. No flow to radiator inlet. ie thermostat exit.

Comment: Are you sure you put the thermostat in the correct way (ie: right side up)? It should have the spring facing down. I'd pull the thermostat and boil it to see if it opens or not. Could be a bad stat.

Comment: Yes I have done that. That's why I'm perplexed.

Comment: Did you ensure there was nothing stuck in the new radiator which could be blocking the flow? Peanuts anyone? Those things are a PITB! You could test things by taking the stat out altogether and running it to check to see if flow is good. It comes down to three things in my mind: 1) Stat not working right; 2) waterpump isn't pumping; 3) new radiator is plugged. SBC's are pretty simple animals when it comes to the cooling department.

Comment: That year uses a left hand rotation water pump (serpentine belt drive) earlier years with v belts used a right hand rotation. Be sure you got the correct pump, they look identical on the outside.

Comment: @Moab - I never realized this. Found [this image which backs what you state](https://www.2carpros.com/img/diagrams/drivebelt/50C00630.gif) ... This would definitely cause the issue, not only with overall flow amount but with direction of flow as well. Great call.

Comment: I am more used to seeing upper/top radiator hose or lower/bottom radiator hose. I am not used to the terms passenger side or driver side with respect to radiator hoses